# Newly developed and deployed eclipse plugins doesn't start automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We have around 5-6 Eclipse new project wizard plugins, when I run from my development environment it runs fine (ie from Eclipse SDK) but if I export it as a plugin jar files and drop it under plugins/dropins folder of newly downloaded eclipse, I am not able to see new wizards in new project wizard.

When I open Eclipse OSGi console and I tried this command:

```
ss
```

and plugins status I got as:

```
421 STARTING    com.example.wizardOne_1.0.0
422 STARTING    com.example.wizardTwo_1.0.0
```

and when I executed this command (to know reason why it hasn't started):

```
diag 421
```

I got output as:

```
reference:file:plugins/com.example.wizardOne_1.0.0 [421]
No unresolved constraints.
```

It means there is no unresolved constraints or other error, so shouldn't it be started automatically. I can understand Eclipse uses Lazy loading concept, but when I open New project wizard it should start that plugin right?

Can anyone help me how to make sure newly deployed plugins starts automatically? Is there any configuration should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you need to use the `clean` option to load the fresh plugins properly. Here are the details of `clean` option taken from : 
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html

> if set to "true", any cached data used by the OSGi framework and
>   eclipse runtime will be wiped clean. This will clean the caches used
>   to store bundle dependency resolution and eclipse extension registry
>   data. Using this option will force eclipse to reinitialize these
>   caches.

This is how you can set it:

- Edit the eclipse.ini file located in your Eclipse install directory
  and insert -clean as the first line.

Or

- Edit the shortcut you use to start Eclipse and add -clean as the
  first argument.

Comment: I tried same, still noting is detecting. But shows all of my plugin is "List of Installed Plugins" in Help window.